# How to unpack variable length data in python struct

Tags: python, struct, bittorrent

I am building a p2p application where it is necessary for me to unpack an udp announce response from the tracker.

```
announce response:

Offset      Size            Name            
0           32-bit integer  action        
4           32-bit integer  transaction_id
8           32-bit integer  interval
12          32-bit integer  leechers
16          32-bit integer  seeders
20 + 6 * n  32-bit integer  IP address
24 + 6 * n  16-bit integer  TCP port
20 + 6 * N
```

I need to read all the data listed in name field from the above table, but the values of seeders, ip address and port are variable.

how do i unpack all the data from the response properly using python struct ?

Comment: Why don't you want to use python struct ?

Comment: yup i am using that ... but struct.unpack('>iiiiih', announse_response)  doesn't work all time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `struct` module is pretty usefull for unpacking binary data.

```
action, transaction_id, interval, leechers, seeders = struct.unpack('>iiiii', announse_response)
```

You then have to loop over the rest of the data to get all ip/port data:

```
ip_port_list = []
while True:
    try: ip_port_list.append(struct.unpack('>ih', announse_response))
    except: break
```

Without struct you will have to read byte by byte and then convert the big endian problem.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same struggle, so wrote a simple package for this called [binread](https://github.com/remopas/binread).

```py
from binread import formatclass, U32, U16, Array 

@formatclass
class Seeder:
    ip_addr = U32
    tcp_port = U16

@formatclass
class AnnounceResponse:
    action = U32
    transaction_id = U32
    interval = U32
    leechers = U32
    seeders = U32

    # `length` refers to the value of the previous `seeders` field
    seeder_data = Array(Seeder, length="seeders")

# `data` is a bytes object
resp = AnnounceResponse.read(data)

print(resp.transaction_id)
print(len(resp.seeder_data))
print(resp.seeder_data[0].tcp_port)
```

You could optionally specify the endianness for all values with `@formatclass(byteorder='little')` (or `'big'`).

*Full disclosure, I am the author of binread.*